# Execute a command in a function displaying real-time output

Tags: bash

In some Bash scripts I am executing some commands preserving the real-time output in this way:

```
exec 5>&1
output=$(ls -1 2>&1 |tee /dev/fd/5; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]})
status=$?
```

I moved this piece of code in a function to make it reusable like this:

```
execute() {
    # 1 - Execute backup
    echo "Executing command 'very_long_command'..."
    exec 5>&1
    cmd="very_long_command"
    output=$($cmd 2>&1 |tee /dev/fd/5; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]})
    status=$?
    echo $output
    echo "very_long_command exited with status $status."
    return $status
}
```

When I call the function with `exec_output="$(execute)"` I can of course get its output, but what I still need is to get the output of `very_long_command` during its execution, and not at the end in a unique output.

Could you help me to achieve this?

Comment: How are you calling the `execute()` function with the arguments?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "real-time"? What does `execute` do instead that you aren't expecting?

Comment: @chepner, I mean that when `execute` runs some commands which take a lot of time I want to see their output during their execution and not after the finish in a single output.

Comment: @Mat, maybe putting `unbuffer` command can help ya.

Comment: @Mihir, I tried putting `unbuffer`behind the command into the `output` function [`output=$(unbuffer ls -1 2>&1 |tee /dev/fd/5; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]})`] but nothing changed..

Comment: Why are you making FD 5 a copy of *stdout* if you want it to be unbuffered? Use stderr for that -- it's defined by the standard for use for "diagnostic" output, and showing your users a trace of active logging is *definitely* diagnostic in nature; moreover, stderr is unbuffered by default, whereas stdout is line-buffered.

Comment: Also, note that `echo $output` is itself buggy; always quote, as in `echo "$output"` -- see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Comment: @Inian, I edited the question adding more information and the call example.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, because I still need the stdout to have the output of the function. I tried to redirect 5>&2 instad of 5>&1, this way I'm getting the output during the execution of the command but I don't get the output of the function..

Comment: @Mat, yes, I agree you want to echo to stdout, but you should *tee* to stderr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to **@Charles Duffy** I solved my problem, redirecting FD 5 to stderr:

```
execute() {
    exec 5>&2
    output=$(ls -1 2>&1 | tee /dev/fd/5; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]})
    status=$?
    echo "$output"
    return $status
}

output="$(execute)"
echo "Function output:"
printf "%s\n" "$output"
```

Comment: If you use `set -o pipefail`, you won't need the `exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}`.

Comment: BTW, you should be able to avoid the use of FD 5, and tee direct to `/dev/fd/2`.