# Bash: get the status of a printed function

Tags: bash

A bash function is called from another function, which needs to print its output and get its returned status code:

```
cmd="/usr/bin/foo_cmd"

# Print message both to stdout and FD5 (I need this because I have to print the message during the script execution and have it sent via e-mail)
msg() {
    msg="$1"
    echo "$msg" | tee /dev/fd/5
}

# Command execution
cmd_exec() {
    cmd="$1"
    exec 5>&2
    output=$($cmd 2>&1 |tee /dev/fd/5; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]})
    status=$?
    echo "Exit status code: $status"
    echo "$output"
    return $status
}

main() {
    exec 5>&2
    echo $(cmd_exec "$cmd")
    status=$?
    msg "Function exit status code: ${status}"
    if [ "$status" -ne "0" ]; then
        ... do something ...
    fi

    return $status
}

mail_text="$(main)"
status=$?

# Check exit status code and compose the mail message
if [ "$status" -ne "0" ]; then
    ... do something ...
fi

... do something else ...
```

The main function always get status code 0 because it's not the status code of `$cmd` but of `echo`.

How can fix this getting the real status code of `$cmd`?

Comment: Is `mktemp` so much hassle?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand why mktemp could help me..

Comment: Remove all the `| tee` and `exec 5>&2`, just `$cmd > tempfile; status=$?`. By design, second file descriptor is a "stadard error" - it's designed for printing errors, not notifying user.

Comment: I cannot redirect stdout to a file because I need "real-time" output of the command, because it can be a very time expensive command (please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57362536/execute-a-command-in-a-function-displaying-real-time-output/57371610?noredirect=1#comment101243009_57371610)

Comment: Well, so you have to go with this

Comment: Why do you need to `echo` something that already echoes? Just do `cmd_exec "$cmd"` without the `echo` and the command substitution.

Answer (score 1):

First point:

The

```
 echo $(cmd_exec "$cmd")
```

will always return with success, as `echo` returns with success.

You should first save the command substitution in a variable, then call echo:

```
 var="$(cmd_exec "$cmd")"
 status="$?"
 echo "$var"
```

The command substitution return with the exit status of the last command executed and variable substitution preserved the `$( ... )` exit status if there's only one `$( ... )`.

Second point:

From [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html):

> The exit status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last command in the pipeline, unless the pipefail option is enabled (see The Set Builtin). If pipefail is enabled, the pipeline’s return status is the value of the last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if all commands exit successfully.

You could use `set -o pipefail` instead of `echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}` to check the return status of both `tee` and `$cmd`.